# How to Mock client side rest service

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

I'm trying to create mockito test run for rest api below is the controller class followed by mock test which I'm trying to execute but the problem is it is still calling actual rest api instead of mocking it,

1) Controller Class

```
public void sendData(ID id, String xmlString, Records record) throws  ValidationException{
        ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new
                HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClients.createDefault());
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
        messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

        MultiValueMap<String,String> header = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        header.add("x-api-key",api_key);
        header.add("Content-Type",content_type);
        header.add("Cache-Control",cache_control);
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(xmlString, header);

        try {
            restTemplate.postForEntity(getUri(id,record), request, String.class);
        }catch (RestClientResponseException e){
            throw new ValidationException("Error occurred while sending a file to some server "+e.getResponseBodyAsString());
        }

    }
```

2) Test class

```
     @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
        public class Safe2RestControllerTest {
            private MockRestServiceServer server;
            private RestTemplate restTemplate;
            private restControllerClass serviceToTest;

         @Before
         public void init(){
         //some code for initialization of the parameters used in controller class    

         this.server = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(this.restTemplate).ignoreExpectOrder(true).build();
         }

          @Test
            public void testSendDataToSafe2() throws ValidationException, URISyntaxException {

            //some code here when().then()

            String responseBody = "{\n" +
                        "    \"responseMessage\": \"Validation succeeded, message 
                             accepted.\",\n" +
                        "    \"responseCode\": \"SUCCESS\",\n" +
                        "    2\"responseID\": \"627ccf4dcc1a413588e5e2bae7f47e9c::0d86869e-663a-41f0-9f4c-4c7e0b278905\"\n" +
                        "}";

           this.server.expect(MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(uri))
          .andRespond(MockRestResponseCreators.withSuccess(responseBody, 
           MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

            serviceToTest.sendData(id, xmlString, record);
            this.server.verify();
            }
        }
```

How should I go ahead, any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring's MVC test apparatus makes this quite easy.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = YourController.class)
public class YourControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testSendDataToSafe2() throws Exception {
        // prepare e.g. create the requestBody

        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(post(uri).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(requestBody))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();

        Assert.assertEquals(responseBody, mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    }
}
```

For more details, see the section titled "**Add Unit Tests**" [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) and/or the section titled "**Auto-configured Spring MVC tests**" [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html).

Your question also states "the problem is it is still calling actual rest api" so I'm guessing that, in addition to calling your controller is a test context, you want that mock out some of the behaviour of that controller. Specifically, you want to mock the `RestTemplate` instance used in that controller. If so, then would have to change the controller implementation such that the `RestTemplate` instance is an `@Autowired` class member. Then you would declare a mock for that in your test case  like so:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = YourController.class)
public class YourControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testSendDataToSafe2() throws Exception {
        // prepare e.g. create the requestBody

        // tell your mocked RestTemplate what to do when it is invoked within the controller
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(..., ..., ...)).thenReturn(...);

        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(post(uri).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(requestBody))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();

        Assert.assertEquals(responseBody, mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    }
}
```

The above code is valid for `spring-test:4.3.10.RELEASE`.

Comment: This: `.andExpect(status().isOk())` is just a conveneince method for checing the HTTP status. You can remove it and check the status explicitly.

Comment: I still have a question, when I'm trying to debug it to see how its working  its not even stopping at any breakpoint, and not also stopping at controller class where I have breakpoints there too, What it is testing actually. not understanding this

Comment: I don't think I can explain why your execution is not stopping at your  breakpoints (perhaps your debugger is not attached to the JVM in which the test is running?) however I can state that there's no magic here; MockMVC only mocks out the servlet mappings etc and creates a controller instance with injected mocks aside from that the code under test *is* your actual code.